# Regex to exclude varying part of a URL in redirection

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm looking to redirect images on a WordPress install as such:

From:

```
https://example.com/uploads/folder/123/image.jpg
https://example.com/uploads/folder/123/image-small.jpg
https://example.com/uploads/folder/123/image-medium.jpg
https://example.com/uploads/folder/123/image-large.jpg
```

To a unique:

```
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg
```

The goal is to have all the variations (normal, small, medium and large) to redirect from that old folder to a unique image in the new one. I have been able to achieve that with the [Redirection plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/), using a series of Regex:

```
/uploads/folder/\d{1,3}/(.*).jpg
/wp-content/uploads/$1.jpg

/uploads/folder/\d{1,3}/(.*)-small(.*)
/wp-content/uploads/$1$2

/uploads/folder/\d{1,3}/(.*)-medium(.*)
/wp-content/uploads/$1$2

/uploads/folder/\d{1,3}/(.*)-large(.*)
/wp-content/uploads/$1$2
```

But that seems not efficient, and I would like to have one regex to rule them all…

I tried different ways to unify all the cases in one Regex but couldn't do it (the ways of excluding I found wouldn't allow me to pass the `$1` and `$2` to rewrite the URL properly). I know this is probably very basic, but I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work:

```
/uploads/folder/\d{1,3}/(.*?)(?:-small|-medium|-large)?(\.\w+)
/wp-content/uploads/$1$2
```

Note that `.` in regex means any character, and regex quantifiers are greedy by default (e.g. matching as far as possible). So having `.*` is often calling for trouble.

Comment: It does work like a charm, thanks! I added a ^ at the start of the expression to prevent a greedy regular expression.

Comment: If you don’t mind, are the interrogation points the key to this regex?

Comment: `(?:)` is a non-capturing group, so that `$2` in the replacement does not contain this group's capture. The `.*?` modifies the `*` quantifier to be lazy. Note that your `^` at the start of the regex will not make it lazy, but make sure that it only matches at the beginning of the URL.